# Changing MainActivity entry while integrating React native and android application

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, kotlin

I am are working on POC to integrate native android app with React Native. After following all steps in react native official docs for integration, I had an error MainActivity.java does not exist. Not sure but I guess its cosreact-native run-android works through MainActivity.java. But in native android app we dun have any such activity file. From AndroidManifest.xml it looks this is the first activity:

```
<application
    android:name=".core.exampleApplication"
```

so to customize to this activity file, I came across cli option :

```
yarn react-native run-android --main-activity core.exampleApplication
```

but it throws this error:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.comp.android/.core.exampleApplication }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.comp.android/com.comp.android.core.exampleApplication} does not exist.
```

package name/applicationId is `com.comp.android`

anyone got an idea how to fix this? or any experience you guys want to share?

Edit intent filter looks like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                   android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" /> -->
</activity>
```

Comment: You confused `Activity` with `Application` class. What activity your manifest contains?

Comment: @VadimGoroshevsky Maybe I am not native developer and Manifest file contains multiple activties. Our Android project doesn't contain any MainActivity.java. So can you please suggest where I can find equivalent to that in code? I thought application name `.core.exampleApplication` might be the first activity.

Comment: Did you take `package name/applicationId is com.comp.android` from `AndroidManifest` or from `build.gradle`?

Comment: I took from apps build.gradle, AndroidManifest mentions just this with applicationId: `android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"`

Comment: `AndroidManifest` has root tag `<manifest>` with attribute `package`. Is it the same as `applicationId`?

Comment: `android/app/build.gradle`, `android/app/src/main/java/com/app/MainActivity.java`,
`android/app/src/main/java/com/app/MainApplication.java`, `android>app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml package/applicationId` was not same in these 4, 

I updated and now it works fine.

Comment: It worked now it doesn't not sure what's an issue, @VadimGoroshevsky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174957/activity-class-rcm-samapp-com-comp-android-ui-does-not-exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into `AndroidManifest.xml` and search for `<activity>` tag which contains this code:

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

After you identified your activity, run command `yarn react-native run-android --main-activity com.comp.android.core.YOUR_ACTIVITY`. Pay your attention to full package name, your activity may not be part of `.core` package.

**EDIT:**
Use command `yarn react-native run-android --main-activity ui.SplashActivity`. Sorry, now I read `react-native-cli` code and you don't need full package name here

Comment: Yes there is Launcher intent filter, I was confusing it with class. Activity name is SplashActivity and its first line mentions `com.comp.android.ui` so I used `yarn react-native run-android --main-activity com.comp.android.ui.SplashActivity`. But now it gives an error:

 
 ```Starting: Intent { cmp=com.comp.android/.com.comp.android.ui.SplashActivity }
     Error type 3
     Error: Activity class 
     {com.comp.android/com.comp.android.com.comp.android.ui.SplashActivity} does not 
      exist.```

Comment: Please take a look at edited post. Sorry, now I read `react-native-cli` code and you don't need full package name here

Comment: I tried from root and android folder both: `yarn react-native run-android --main-activity ui.SplashActivity` Error: Activity class {com.comp.android/com.comp.android.ui.SplashActivity} does not exist.

Comment: I have added full intent filter if it helps.

Comment: Alot of searching! This is the one that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`yarn react-native run-android --main-activity .ui.SplashActivity`

**Must add a 'dot'**