React Native android:networkSecurityConfig make app can start
I need to use this line
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

inside AndroidManifest because I need to load untrusted website. But it's make my app can not loading by this error:
Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged

Remove this line then app start normally. I dont know why, can someone help me?

This question is similar to: Running RN View in existing android app gives error Unable to load script. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

this solution worked to me
<domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.3.2</domain>

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63286158/1308590
